# Forwarding packets using Fluentd

Tags: udp, fluentd

I have the following code in my Fluentd config:

```
<source>
  @type udp
  tag traceudp
  port 3543
  format none
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>
```

This is a plugin that receives udp package and if I send that to stdout I see the contents of the message. Now I would like to send this message forward to another UDP receiver without any changes to the UDP package. How could I do that and what output plugin should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with forward plugin (https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/out_forward).

Something like this:

```
<source>
  @type udp
  @label @udp_stream
  tag traceudp
  port 3543
  format none
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>

<label @udp_stream>
  <match **>
    @type forward
    send_timeout 60s
    recover_wait 10s
    hard_timeout 60s

    <server>
      name myserver1
      host 192.168.1.3   <---- your server IP
      port 3543
      weight 60
  </server>
  </match>
</label>
```